# My Third "Grab Object in Django" Post

Tags: python, django

Clearly I am struggling with various permutations of grabbing objects in Django. Here's another.

This is for the same library app I've been working on (in case you have seen my other questions).

On the home page, I display the active user's name and information (this works fine). Then I wish to display all of the reviews that the active user has written. I am basically able to do this as well, except it just shows the reviews with no reference to the books they are supposed to describe.

So... I need to be able to grab the Book object by its Review object. In other words, each time I display a Review, I want to be able to grab the Book (title and author) that it pertains to. Keep in mind that I can't grab the Book by the User (using created_by), because a user can write reviews for books that they did not add to the db. I hope this makes sense but I'm sure you can see that I am struggling with such problems.

In models.py, I set up my tables like this (keep in mind that the User table is in a different app):

```
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    author = models.ForeignKey("Author", on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="books")

    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="books_added")
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    objects = BookManager()

class Author(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    objects = AuthorManager()

class Review(models.Model):
    rating = models.IntegerField()
    comments = models.TextField()

    book = models.ForeignKey("Book", on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="reviews")

    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="reviews_added")
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    objects = ReviewManager()
```

Then in views.py I am trying to define a variable "book" by referencing the Review object (since book is a field within review). Like so:

```
def books_home(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        first_name = User.objects.get(id=request.session['uid']).first_name
        last_name = User.objects.get(id=request.session['uid']).last_name
        email = User.objects.get(id=request.session['uid']).email
        user_id = User.objects.get(id=request.session['uid']).id
        reviews = Review.objects.filter(created_by=user_id)
        book = Review.objects.filter(created_by=user_id).book
        context = {
            'first_name' : first_name, 
            'email' : email,
            'last_name' : last_name,
            'reviews' : reviews,
            'book' : book
            }
        return render(request, 'html_files/home.html', context=context)
```

Keep in mind that essentially everything in here works except `book = Review.objects.filter(created_by=user_id).book' and`'book' : book` in the context dict.

Also keep in mind that I am very new to Django and to programming in general. I'm sure there are more elegant ways to do this, but I am sticking to methods that I understand, so in answering, please try to stick as close to my current code as possible. "Make it work, then make it work better."

I believe I know what to do in the template to show the context dict, so that is not a problem. The code is on GitHub if that would help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The Review filter will return a queryset of reviews, that can be one or more instances of Book, so you can't access `.book` on a query set.

From which of those reviews would you like to return a book?

Instead, in the template, use `{{ review.book }}` to access the book for each review. To prevent it hitting the db for each book access, use `select_related()`.

The db access in general is not optimal, you're hitting the db multiple times (each `.get()`). Instead, access it once, and store in a variable.

Plus, when you filter on the user, filter using the user instance itself, Django will handle the bookkeeping:

```
        user = User.objects.get(id=request.session['uid'])
        reviews = Review.objects.filter(created_by=user)
```

However, you've already defined `related_name` for the reverse foreign key relations, why not use it?

Modify to something like:

```
def books_home(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        user = User.objects.get(id=request.session['uid'])
        reviews = user.reviews_added.select_related('book')
        context = {
            'first_name' : user.first_name, 
            'email' : user.email,
            'last_name' : user.last_name,
            'reviews' : reviews,
            }
        return render(request, 'html_files/home.html', context=context)
```

Each review will have the related book instance on it, so in the template:

```
{% for review in reviews %}
   {{ review.book.title }}
{% endfor %}
```

For info see [Related objects reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/relations/).

Comment: PS, if you;'re using `django,contrib.auth` the current user will be available with `request.user`.

Comment: Thank you for this. It will take me a while to process and put this into my code... I'll let you know how it goes!